# Angular logs HTTP error before handling it

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following mechanism (ignore the simplicity for the moment please) when a user clicks on a button on a dead simple login form:

```
$scope.login = function () {
    $http.post('/rest/authenticate', {
        userName: $scope.userName,
        password: $scope.password
    }).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //handle success, etc
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            //hanlde errors, etc
        });
};
```

The method is calling a REST service that could return a String as an answer if the proper credentials are provided or an error (400, 401) if they are not good. The success method gets executed when the good user/pass is given and the error function also executes if the REST call returns some HTTP error.

My problem is that if any kind of error happens, BEFORE the error method gets executed, angular displays the error in the browser console like this:

```
POST http://server.address/rest/authenticate 400 (Bad Request)
```

This originates from angular.js (line 8113):

```
xhr.send(post || null);
```

It even displays it *before* a http interceptor's 'responseError' method. Using non-compressed angular version 1.2.14

How can I turn this unnecessary logging off?

Comment: This comes from the browser itself, not from angular.

Comment: How does that bother you? The developer is usually the only one with an open console and he usually wants to know what happens. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

zeroflagL's comment is valid and I found no solution to this "issue"